# Panda: data manipulation per pivot table

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am new to Panda and need to automate a report that was  presented earlier using excel and pivot table.
I dont understand pivot table that much either.

Since I know python I thought I could use that.
I've worked on `csv-reader` , csv-writer`and`openpyxl`.

I thought `panda` would be good to use  for data analysis and I could do this with minimal code.

Instead of going line by line using `openpyxl` or `csv reader/writer`
However, since I am new, I am struggling with how to get this done in `panda`

Here is a sample dataframe

[image]

Edit : In text format

```
serial_number   item_name   status  date
1   foo1        done           2015-01-11
2   foo2        done           2016-01-11
3   foo3        not_done       2015-02-12
4   foo4        not_done       2016-01-12
5   foo5        on_hold        2015-03-13
6   foo6        not_done       2016-02-13
7   foo7        done           2016-03-14
8   foo7        done           2016-02-15
9   foo8        not_done       2016-03-16
10  foo8        on_hold        2016-04-17
11  foo9        on_hold        2016-04-18
```

From excel manipulation it gives following report

[image]

Edit: In text format

```
        Status          
Year    Start_Month done    not_done    on_hold total
2015    January      1       0          0        1
        February     0       1          0        1
        March        0       0          1        1
2016    January      1       1          0        2
        February     1       1          0        2
        March        1       1          0        2
        April        0       0          2        2
Grand_Total          4       4          3        11
```

Her is my attempt to write a pivot_table for above manipulation

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["donel","not_done","on_hold"],\
 index=["date"], columns=["status"]
```

And, here is the error message I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["Implementation - Successful","Closed Incomplete","Backed Out"], index=["chg_year","chg_month"], columns=["chg_state"]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\pivot.py", line 121, in pivot_table
    agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3597, in aggregate
    return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3114, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(arg, _level=_level, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 428, in _aggregate
    return getattr(self, arg)(*args, **kwargs), None
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 964, in mean
    return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3048, in _cython_agg_general
    how, numeric_only=numeric_only)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3094, in _cython_agg_blocks
    raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, please provide your sample data in text format — or, better yet, as code that produces it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'serial_number': range(1, 12),
                   'item_name': list(map(lambda x: 'foo' + str(x),
                                         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9])),
                   'status': ['done', 'done', 'not_done', 'not_done', 'on_hold',
                              'not_done', 'done', 'done', 'not_done', 'on_hold',
                              'on_hold'],
                   'date': ['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2015-02-12', '2016-01-12',
                            '2015-03-13', '2016-02-13', '2016-03-14', '2016-02-15',
                            '2016-03-16', '2016-04-17', '2016-04-18']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Use `pd.crosstab` (rather than `pd.pivot_table`) and resample by month.

```
output = pd.crosstab(df['date'], df['status']).resample('M').sum().dropna()
```

Compute the totals for each row.

```
output['total'] = output.sum(axis=1)
```

Reindex to get nicely formatted year and month as in your desired output.

```
dates = output.index.to_series()
output.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [dates.dt.year, dates.dt.strftime('%B')],
    names=['Year', 'Start_Month'])
print(output)

# status            done  not_done  on_hold  total
# Year Start_Month                                
# 2015 January       1.0       0.0      0.0    1.0
#      February      0.0       1.0      0.0    1.0
#      March         0.0       0.0      1.0    1.0
# 2016 January       1.0       1.0      0.0    2.0
#      February      1.0       1.0      0.0    2.0
#      March         1.0       1.0      0.0    2.0
#      April         0.0       0.0      2.0    2.0
```

The totals by column have no place in the same dataframe.

```
grand_total = output.sum()
print(grand_total)

# status
# done         4.0
# not_done     4.0
# on_hold      3.0
# total       11.0
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Alberto, I did update question with sample data in text format. A little late though. Your answer is closest to my requirement. One question though, Is it possible to store `item_name` for each category? For e.g. `2015` `January` `done` category, how can I store `foo1` as item name. My next step is to port this to html so that  I can provide hyperlinks to each non-zero catagory to refer back to original item. May be store them in an list to be accessed later?

Comment: @Anil_M: that's a different problem. May I suggest you post it as another question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    #break out month and year
    df.loc[:, 'month'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
    df.loc[:, 'year'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
    #aggregate with column headers as 'status' values
    df.pivot_table(index = ['month', 'year'], columns = ['status'], values = 'item_name', aggfunc = 'count')
```

yields:

```
status      done  not_done
month year                
1     2016   1.0       NaN
2     2016   NaN       1.0
3     2016   1.0       NaN
4     2016   NaN       1.0
5     2016   1.0       NaN
6     2016   NaN       1.0
7     2016   1.0       NaN
8     2016   1.0       NaN
9     2016   1.0       NaN
10    2016   1.0       NaN
```